# Mixing attributes and aggregate functions in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

Suppose a table with two numeric attributes: `a` and `b`. E.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE Test(a,b);
INSERT INTO Test VALUES(2,20);
INSERT INTO Test VALUES(1,10);
INSERT INTO Test VALUES(3,30);
```

The following query is illegal in some DBMSs (e.g. Oracle), but is legal in SQLite:

```
SELECT a, min(b) FROM Test;
```

For the above data, the query produces a table consisting of one row -- (1, 10). In other words, we succeeded in finding the value of `a` that corresponds to the smallest value of `b`. The question is: is this behavior guaranteed or SQLite has the right to pick the value of `a` arbitrarily?

Comment: probably sqlite uses the first-encountered value(s) for the non-aggregated fields. since `2` is the first record created in the table, that's the value you get for `a`, while `min(b)` will work as expected - the smallest value in b across the entire table. MySQL does the same thing, and while it's not particularly likely to change (e.g. use the last encounter-value) instead, you shouldn't depend on this behavior.

Comment: Because the corresponding value to the smallest value is not defined if you have to rows with b=10 and a differs, I would say it is not guaranteed

Answer (score 2):

This behaviour is guaranteed [since version 3.7.11](http://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_7_11.html).

Comment: Of course, it becomes arbitrary again if multiple rows share the same min value